# Attempting to set a specific pixel in SDL2.0 fails

Tags: c, rendering, sdl-2

I am attempting to write a chip-8 emulator, and already have the processor all wrapped up. I am attempting to write a small program to experiment with rendering a chip-8 ROM in SDL. I have ran into a snag however. In the below program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 320;
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;

void put_pixel_xy(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x, int y, unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 255);
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
}

int main() {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: SDL could not initialize: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Chip-8 Emulator", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error: could not create SDL window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(2000);

    for(int x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; ++x) {
        for(int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT/2; ++y) {
            put_pixel_xy(renderer, x, y, 255, 255, 255);
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    SDL_Delay(5000);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to make half of the screen white, and half black. However, whenever I run this program I get the following result:

[image: SDL Result]

Any help as to why this is happening would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You cleared one buffer, then presented it, then drew to the other buffer (without clearing it) then presented that.  What you drew is there, and correct... but the part you didn't draw on has garbage on it.  Do an `SDL_RenderClear()` before your `for` loop, and *don't* present it until you're done drawing.

Comment: I tested your code, added `int argc, char *argv[]` to `main()`'s arguments to fix the "Undefined reference to 'SDL_main' error, and it works normally.